What can we do for R/Finance 2013?
The R/Finance conference is gearing up for May. Since many of our participants are R users, is there anything we can do to support this? I posted about this conference rather late a couple years ago, so I hope to be proactive this time around.

We (as organizer of the R/Finance conferences) appreciate any and all help and suggestions.

What kind of support are you thinking about?

Nice idea!  Can give out some swag to advertise the site?

@Shane You want to give out Quant.SE swag at R/Finance?

@chrisaycock I would love to, but regretfully I won't be able to attend.  The year that I give the keynote, I promise to wear a Quant.SE tee shirt on stage.
